# xtext not accepting string constant - expecting RULE_ID

Tags: parsing, xtext

I have tried to cut down my problem to the simplest problem I can in xtext - I would like to use the following grammar:

```
M: lines += T*;

T:
    DT
    | BDT
    | N
;

BDT: 
    name = ('a' | 'b' | 'c') 
;

DT: 
     'd' name=ID 
     ('(' (ts += BDT (','ts += BDT)*) ')')? 
;

N: 
     'n' name=ID ':' type=[T]
;
```

I am intending to parse expressions of the form `d f(a,b,b)` for example which works fine. I would also like to be able to parse `n g:f` which also works, but not `n g:a` - where a here is part of the BDT rule. The error given is "Missing RULE_ID at 'a'".

I'd like to allow the grammar to parse `n g:a` for example, and I'd be very grateful if anyone could point out where I'm going wrong here on this very simple grammar.

Comment: To answer my own question (I think) - the problem is that the rule is expecting the ID token but I the name is set to a string constant identifier in the BDT rule. I think the answer here is to change BDT to accept and ID, and then to write a validator to restrict its inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lexing is done context free. A keyword can never be an ID. You can address this trough parser rules.

You can introduce a datatype rule

```
MyID: ID | "a" | ... | "c";
```

And use it where you use ID